# Generic types to achieve contravariant arguments

Tags: java, generics

Let's consider this code:

```
public interface Number {
  public Number plus(Number n);
}

public class Complex implements Number {
  private double re, im;

  public Complex(double re, double im) {
    this.re = re;
    this.im = im;
  }

  @Override
  public Complex plus(Complex c) {
    return new Complex(this.re + c.re, this.im + this.im);
  }
}
```

It wouldn't compile because if `Complex.plus()` overrides `Number.plus()`, its argument must be exactly the same as the overridden method. I thought about using generics for the type of objects a number can interact with, but it produces a very unclean code, with unparametrized use of `Number` and redundancy:

```
public interface Number<T extends Number> {
    public T plus(T n);
}

public class Complex implements Number<Complex> {
    private double re, im;

    public Complex(double re, double im) {
        this.re = re;
        this.im = im;
    }

    @Override
    public Complex plus(Complex c) {
        return new Complex(this.re + c.re, this.im + this.im);
    }
}
```

Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I would do this without the `Number` interface. Unless you can meaningfully add different subtypes of `Number`, having a common interface doesn't obviously serve a purpose.

Comment: I want to keep the interface.

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: How is Complex a super-type here while it implements the interface?

Comment: I mixed up the terms sorry. And I want to keep the interface because I will have different types of numbers and then I want to make matrices with a generic type extending Number.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple fix: make the type parameter self-bounded:

```
public interface Number<T extends Number<T>> {
```

(and then pinky-swear that you'll only ever define a classes that implement the interface for themselves, e.g. `class Self implements Number<Self>`)

---

However, I would do this without the `Number` interface, at least in terms of the `plus` method. Unless you can meaningfully add different subtypes of `Number`, having such a method in the common interface doesn't obviously serve a purpose.

Consider why there are no arithmetic methods defined on the standard `Number` interface.

Instead, don't have the `plus` "operator" in the `Complex` class either: use the standard `BinaryOperator` interface to define a plus operator for specific types:

```
BinaryOperator<Complex> complexPlus = (a, b) -> new Complex(a.re + b.re, a.im + b.im);
BinaryOperator<Integer> integerPlus = (a, b) -> a + b; // Or Integer::sum.
```

and then apply these:

```
Complex complexSum = complexPlus.apply(firstComplex, secondComplex);
Integer integerSum = integerPlus.apply(firstInt, secondInt);
```

Comment: Thank you, it solves the unparametrized use of Number, but not the redundancy problem. There is no way to solve this issue?

Comment: @JacopoStanchi what redundancy?

Comment: The fact that we always have to do Self implements Number<Self> and there is no automatic way to enforce this.

Comment: @JacopoStanchi no, no way. Hence the exhortation to pinky-swear.